# Callback Geocoder

Tags: google-maps-api, geocoding, javascript

Перебираю объекты в которых нужно заполнить lat и lng (координаты), для этого дергаю геокодер. Раньше достаточно было ajax запроса, в котором я посылал id объекта в параметре запроса и потом по this обращался к ниму теперь вот такая шляпа:

**geocode(request:GeocoderRequest, callback:function(Array.<GeocoderResult>, GeocoderStatus))**

вот код из цикла в котором делаю запрос:

```
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode( {
                    address: markers_data[id].location,
                    language: 'ru'
                },
                function(data, status) { 
                        markers_data[id].lat = data[0].geometry.location.hb;
                        markers_data[id].lng = data[0].geometry.location.ib;
                });
```

Вопрос в следующем, как в коллбэк передать id, через параметр запроса не получается, допустимы только параметры *address, bounds, location, region*.
[описалово google.maps.Geocoder class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru-RU#GeocoderRequest)

Comment: чем отличается [key] от [id]?.. вы же берете адрес по одному ключу из массива, а результат уходит к элементу с совершенно другим ключом?..

Comment: key от id ничем не отличается. коллбэк о существовании key ничего не знает

Comment: ну а в чем, собственно, проблема? "шляпа" - это как-то малоинформативно

Comment: коллбеки срабатывают после того как отработал цикл, поэтому в каждом экземпляре коллбека последней id итерации цикла

Comment: да покажите уже весь код, с цилом и т.л. а то гадание на кофейной гуже получается

Comment: в цикле вызывайте свою функцию с геокодером, передавайте в нее id. колбэк ее увидит и передаваться будет нужный индекс, а не последний.

Comment: вот эта функция https://dl.dropbox.com/u/76275290/m.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[замыкания](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure)

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( {
   address: markers_data[id].location,
   language: 'ru'
},
function(_id) {
    return function(data,status){
        markers_data[_id].lat = data[0].geometry.location.hb;
        markers_data[_id].lng = data[0].geometry.location.ib;
    }
}(id));
```

Comment: спасибо, пошел замыкания учить